# How to grant a user certain permission based on his session when filling out a webform in drupal 7?

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

Scenario: the website has a `webform` which the user can fill out and submit. After the form gets submitted, the system creates a PDF file with the user's entered data. The user shall see a download link to that pdf and shall have the access permission to download *this particular* PDF (and not other PDFs of other submissioned webform entries which can be guessed by the url structure for instance).

Any suggestions on how to do this? Any modules which can handle this?
I cannot provide code that I have so far since it has nothing to do with a session related thing. I just guess it has to do with the following hooks:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

}

function mymodule_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {

}

function mymodule_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use rules module to:
- on event (submission of webform)
- asign role 'RoleA' to user that has the associated permissions to see the PDF

then use content_access module to give RoleA the necessary permissions to access the PDF.